# Plus or minus quarters in Google Sheets using formulas

Tags: google-sheets, date, google-sheets-dates

I have a date format like this

```
1Q16
2Q16
3Q16
4Q16
```

Is there a way to get...

input: `1Q16 + 4` output: `1Q17` and...

input: `1Q16 - 3` output: `2Q15`

... using formulas only and not code?

Comment: Are you starting from an actual date? eg: 1/1/2016 Or just your text entered as 1Q16?  The `VALUE()` function along with some arithmetic may be the answer there.  Would depend on your assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mid()` extract the quarter portion of the original date, here after referred to as *Q*. Similarly extract the year portion, here after referred to as *Y*. The amount to be added will be referred to as *D*.

To get the new quarter add *D* to *Q* and modulo by 4. This will be correct except it will equal 0 when it should be 4. Wrap this whole portion in an `if()` to handle that case and we are done.

Moving on to the new year. Add *Y* to the `trunc()` of (*Q*+*D*)/4

When *Q*+*D* is negative or a positive multiple of 4 we end up 1 to high. Add a check for that at the end.

Take these two values and concatenate them with a Q in-between

```
=if(mod(MID(E15,1,1)+F15,4)=0,4,mod(MID(E15,1,1)+F15,4))
&"Q"&mid(E15,3,4)+trunc((MID(E15,1,1)+F15)/4)+
if(or(mod(MID(E15,1,1)+F15,4)=0,MID(E15,1,1)+F15<0),-1,0)
```

Original date is in E15 and the number of quarters to be added to it in F15

This answer is not Y2K compliant, but that's on you and your 2 digit years, if you go to 4 digit you will need to change the `mid()` for the year to be `mid(3,6)`

[MID](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129)

[TRUNC](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093588)

[MOD](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093497)